# Javascript Exact match from HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, string

This question may b a duplicate one..

I have an html string like `<div id=9>Product Sale</div></div>` and `<div id=10 >Sale</div>`.

i want to search 'Sale' from these strings in javascript. I have tries  `(string.indexOf(searchString) > -1)` but this returns me both strings . I just want 1 with the id "10".

Need Help . Regards

Comment: Try: `string.indexOf('id=10') > -1`

Comment: How are you searching the elements? Can you update your question and include the relevant source code? Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS as i said i m trying to search using (string.indexOf(searchString) > -1)

Comment: Well with very little to work with this is all I will offer. `if(document.getElementById('10').innerHTML=="Sale")` or `document.getElementById('10').innerHTML.indexOf('Sale') > -1` if you really want to stick with using indexOf.

Comment: i dnt wanna use the Id instead. Is there a way that i can use the string

Comment: Show more of the search function and I will be happy to help. "As I said" include more relevant source code and I will be happy to help. Or you could give more detail of what you wish to achieve. Why don't you want to use the `ID`? would you be open to use a `class`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(string.indexOf('>' + searchString + '<') > -1)
```

should find the right "Sale"

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Jquery and Include the 1.x version that will support in all browser

```
var salesVal = $('#10').text();
```